# IntelliJ IDEA error: cannot find vm options file

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to launch IntelliJ IDEA but the following error pops up:

> Cannot find vm options file

Comment: Does the file exist?

Comment: I looked into IntelliJ's directory, but i cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Okay.  Three things:  what is your OS?  What version of IntelliJ are you running, and have you upgraded it recently?  Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Windows 10. IntelliJ Community Edition 15.0.3 and have not upgraded it. I was trying to solve the problem without reinstalling it, but I'm going to do it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit solution is to set an environment variable named `$IDEA_VM_OPTION`:

```
export IDEA_VM_OPTION="[path-to-'.vmoptions' file]"
```

Search in the file idea.sh:

```
grep -ri "vmoption" ./bin/idea.sh
```

You will see that the search path for `.vmoptions` file is either:

```
$HOME/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/idea$BITS.vmoptions
```

or

```
$IDE_BIN_HOME/idea$BITS.vmoptions
```

So, copy file `bin/idea64.vmoptions` into one of above locations if you have 64 bit JVM installed or file `bin/idea.vmoptions` else.

Comment: Please use code formatting (four space indent for a block, backlines for inline) to make code snippets more readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me in **Ubuntu 16.4**, and the ***pycharm.vmoptions*** file was under the ***bin/*** directory.

I was trying to run the shell script with this commands:

```
cd <path_to_pycharm_installation>/bin
source pycharm.sh
```

Running the bash script without the "source" command solved it for me:

```
./pycharm.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The following information is current as of April 23, 2019 for version 2019.1.1 of IntelliJ Ultimate ***that was installed via JetBrains Toolbox app version 1.14.5179***

- Locate the start menu item for IntelliJ.  For me, it was at:

  %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\JetBrains Toolbox\

with the name:

```
IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate
```

- right-click on the above item and choose *Properties*
- Change the empty *Start In:* text box to read:
  %LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-U\ch-0\191.6707.61\bin\

Once the above work-around has been performed, IntelliJ 2019.1.1 Ultimate will stop emitting the error: 
*Error launching IDEA cannot find VM options file*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by rename the name of the file running android studio and the file with the .vmoptions extension the same. The name does not have to be the same as mine, you can give it a name you like, matching the naming requirements of the windows/Linux you are using. I think so (^+^).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happens because Idea searches the file `idea64.vmoptions` in folder where I running `idea.sh` from. I.e. I received such error when tried to run `idea.sh` file from any place but not from Idea's bin folder. It's because in default `idea.sh` file the `$IDE_BIN_HOME` variable gets a real path you are running from. Instead of this it should points to Idea's bin folder where `idea.sh` and `idea64.vmoptions` files are.

You can define `$IDE_BIN_HOME` manually or correct the script to define it automatically. In first variant replace the line

```
IDE_BIN_HOME=$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")
```

with

```
IDE_BIN_HOME="path/to/Idea's_bin_folder"
```

For second variant replace that line with

```
IDE_BIN_HOME=$(dirname "$(realpath "${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}")")
```