# VM options files not found, while launching PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, virtual-machine

I recently installed pycharm from the web, and when I try to launch the application, it shows the following message:

> VM options file not found.

I browsed over this site to find answers and found out that the file is present in `bin folder`, but I still could not find it, and another solution was to run `pycharm.sh` at the start, but I cannot find it anywhere yet. So I would request you to guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably in your `bin` folder, `pycharm.vmoptions` file is missing.

If that's the case, create `pycharm.vmoptions` in your `bin` directory and paste the followings:

```sh
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_pycharm_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_pycharm.hprof
```

I've tested in my mac.

Comment: Link [to official site](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties) and [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36585123/).

Comment: Thanks, i should have added to the answer it seems I forgot

Comment: The error message in the question is actually wrong, it should be ["cannot find VM options file"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22cannot%20find%20VM%20options%20file%22). Since the OP is "long gone" and unlikely to come back, I think the best option is to raise a "costum mod flag" and request [a merge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merged-questions) of this question with a better one from the list in this comment. It'll be more useful to readers and will give your answer the visibility it deserves (I just read all the others and I think yours is the best one).

Comment: Thank you very much